# What kind of notification is Firefox sending when a download has finished?

Tags: window-manager, xterm, notifications, dwm

I'm using the [dynamic window manager of suckless](http://dwm.suckless.org/) (dwm). I noticed that `firefox` is able to send nice notifications when a download has finished. See the two figures

[image: no notification]

When I'm on a different tag, I get this kind of notification (inverted `1` tag) upon a finished download.

[image: notification]

I'd like to use this kind of notification for my other `uxterms`. E.g. in case a long job has finished it should light up like above. At best, this would also work inside the `GNU screen` sessions that I'm using.

I'm not sure if this is a `Xorg` or a `dwm` feature. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** The answer of @scai is very much to the point, but lacks the full compatibility with `GNU screen`. In case anybody can still improve this, it'd be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is probably the *urgency hint* which can be set on windows. This hint is recognized by most window managers.

Most terminals can be configured to set the urgency hint when receiving a *bell*.
*(u)xterm* for example has the `bellIsUrgent` option and *(u)rxvt* has `urgentOnBell`.

To ring the bell in a terminal just run `tput bel` or `echo "\a"` (depending on the shell you might need to pass option `-e` to echo).

When using `screen` you have to turn off the *visual* bell and turn on the *audible* bell via `vbell off` in your *screenrc* or by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>.

Comment: yes sir! `tput bel` and `xterm*bellIsUrgent: true` is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: it works almost perfectly, thanks! The audible bell in `screen`, however, works only if it is triggered from the visible screen-tab...

Comment: @Sebastian Ah that's true, I wonder whether this is a bug or if it can be turned off by some configuration option.

Comment: this helped me a lot already though. I'll try to figure this out. Or maybe others have a clue?